webpack-dev-server electronjs with reactjs configuraction
I have a problem with electronjs app with reactjs using webpack-dev-server.
I trying to
npm start

that setup and in console application is starting succesfuly but application window does not showing up and even if i run http://localhost:8080/ still nothing.
My file configuration and setup:
webpack.dev.config.js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: "defaults" }]],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        use: [{ loader: "file-loader?name=img/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]" }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "file-loader?name=font/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  target: "electron-renderer",
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: "React Electron App" }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
    }),
  ],
  devtool: "cheap-source-map"
};


package.json scripts:
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config webpack.build.config.js && electron --noDevServer .",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js --mode development",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.build.config.js --mode production",
    "package": "npm run build",
    "postpackage": "electron-packager ./ --out=./release-builds"
  },

main.js
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

let mainWindow;

let isDev = false;

if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV !== undefined &&
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
) {
  isDev = true;
}

function createMainWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1100,
    height: 800,
    show: isDev ? true : false,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    icon: `${__dirname}/assets/icon.png`,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contentSecurityPolicy: "default-src 'self'",
    },
  });

  let indexPath;

  if (isDev && process.argv.indexOf("--noDevServer") === -1) {
    indexPath = url.format({
      protocol: "http:",
      host: "localhost:8000",
      pathname: "index.html",
      slashes: true,
    });
  } else {
    indexPath = url.format({
      protocol: "file:",
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"),
      slashes: true,
    });
  }

  mainWindow.loadURL(indexPath);

  // Don't show until we are ready and loaded
  mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    mainWindow.show();

    // Open devtools if dev
    if (isDev) {
      const {
        default: installExtension,
        REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS,
      } = require("electron-devtools-installer");

      installExtension(REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS).catch((err) =>
        console.log("Error loading React DevTools: ", err)
      );
      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
  });

  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
}

app.on("ready", createMainWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createMainWindow();
  }
});

// Stop error
app.allowRendererProcessReuse = true;


eventually you can take full code from here:
simple-electronjs-boilerplate
documentation of webpack dev server, webpack configuration, chatgpt, google

Your start script doesn't call the electron command.

But it does not change anything.

What doesn't change anything?
